# polymer paper-dialog within paper-dialog

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying to make the confirmation dialog show up after I tap on affirmative button on "base" dialog. This confirmation dialog never appears. Instead, the "base" dialog closes immediately when I tap on its affirmative button.

How do I fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

file **confirm-dialog.html**:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/PolymerElements/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<dom-module id="confirm-dialog">
    <template>
        <paper-dialog>
            <h2>[[msgHeader]]</h2>
            <content></content>
            <div class="buttons">
                <paper-button dialog-dismiss>[[msgDismiss]]</paper-button>
                <paper-button dialog-confirm>[[msgConfirm]]</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({
    is:'confirm-dialog'
    ,behaviors:[Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior]
    ,properties:{
        msgHeader:String
        ,msgDismiss:String
        ,msgConfirm:String
    }
    ,show:function(){
        this.$$("paper-dialog").open();
    }
});
</script>
```

file **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
    <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/PolymerElements/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="confirm-dialog.html">
</head>
<body>
<dom-module id="dialog-in-dialog">
    <template>
        <button on-tap="Button1Clicked">Open Base Dialog</button>
        <paper-dialog id="base">
            <h2>Base Dialog</h2>
            <p>This is base dialog.</p>
            <confirm-dialog msg-header="Confirm Dialog" msg-dismiss="Cancel" msg-confirm="Do it">Sure want to break the window?</confirm-dialog>
            <div class="buttons">
                <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
                <paper-button dialog-confirm on-tap="OpenDialog2">Break the window</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    var init=function(){
        Polymer({
            is:"dialog-in-dialog"
            ,Button1Clicked:function(){
                this.$.base.open();
            }
            ,OpenDialog2:function(){
                this.$$("confirm-dialog").show();
            }
        });
    };
    if(HTMLImports.ready)
        init();
    else
        HTMLImports.whenReady(init);
</script>
<dialog-in-dialog></dialog-in-dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">


<dom-module id="confirm-dialog">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog>
      <h2>[[msgHeader]]</h2>
      <content></content>
      <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>[[msgDismiss]]</paper-button>
        <paper-button dialog-confirm>[[msgConfirm]]</paper-button>
      </div>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'confirm-dialog',
    behaviors: [Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior],
    properties: {
      msgHeader: String,
      msgDismiss: String,
      msgConfirm: String
    },
    show: function() {
      this.$$("paper-dialog").open();
    }
  });
</script>



<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="dialog-in-dialog">
    <template>
      <button on-tap="Button1Clicked">Open Base Dialog</button>
      <paper-dialog id="base">
        <h2>Base Dialog</h2>
        <p>This is base dialog.</p>
        <confirm-dialog msg-header="Confirm Dialog" msg-dismiss="Cancel" msg-confirm="Do it">Sure want to break the window?</confirm-dialog>
        <div class="buttons">
          <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
          <paper-button dialog-confirm on-tap="OpenDialog2">Break the window</paper-button>
        </div>
      </paper-dialog>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <script>
    var init = function() {
      Polymer({
        is: "dialog-in-dialog",
        Button1Clicked: function() {
          this.$.base.open();
        },
        OpenDialog2: function() {
          this.$$("confirm-dialog").show();
        }
      });
    };
    if (HTMLImports.ready)
      init();
    else
      HTMLImports.whenReady(init);
  </script>
  <dialog-in-dialog></dialog-in-dialog>
</body>

</html>
```

*[edit]*
I want the parent `paper-dialog` keep opened after its child `paper-dialog` is opened. According to the helps from the kind guru, I remove `paper-button` from the parent `paper-dialog` as shown in this revision:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="../bc/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../bc/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bc/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bc/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="confirm-dialog.html">
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id="dialog-in-dialog">
        <template>
            <button on-tap="Button1Clicked">Open Base Dialog</button>
            <paper-dialog id="base">
                <h2>Base Dialog</h2>
                <p>This is base dialog.</p>
                <button on-tap="OpenDialog2">Break the window</button>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Exit</paper-button>
                </div>
            </paper-dialog>
            <confirm-dialog msg-header="Confirm Dialog" msg-dismiss="Cancel" msg-confirm="Do it">Sure want to break the window?</confirm-dialog>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        var init=function(){
            Polymer({
                is:"dialog-in-dialog"
                ,Button1Clicked:function(){
                    this.$.base.open();
                }
                ,OpenDialog2:function(){
                    this.$$("confirm-dialog").show();
                }
            });
        };
        if(HTMLImports.ready)
            init();
        else
            HTMLImports.whenReady(init);
    </script>
    <dialog-in-dialog></dialog-in-dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some tip URLs to `polygit` are all `https` and not `http` and for `Polymer elements` url need not contain `PolymerElements` in the url e.g for `paper-button` url will be _https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html_ and not _https://polygit.org/components/PolymerElements/paper-button/paper-button.html_

Comment: @a1626: Thanks a lot for the precious tips not easy to find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes to your current code to make it work

- 1. You need to remove `behavior` from your `confirm-dialog` item. As your element in itself is not going to open and is just gonna call `paper-dialog`'s `open` function internally there is no need to import `PaperDialogBehavior` in your custom element.
- 2. You need to remove `dialog-confirm` from the button which you are going to use to open the nested dialog. Adding that will close your parent dialog and thus your attempt to open nested dialog will fail.

or

- 2. If you want to close your first dialog and open the second dialog you can instead of removing `dialog-confirm` can move your `custom-dialog` element out of the `paper-dialog`. This will on click of the button close the parent dialog and open the child dialog as depicted in the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8A9Im0Ri9D8biWi8Clfp)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="confirm-dialog">
    <template>
      <paper-dialog>
        <h2>[[msgHeader]]</h2>
        <content></content>
        <div class="buttons">
          <paper-button dialog-dismiss>[[msgDismiss]]</paper-button>
          <paper-button dialog-confirm>[[msgConfirm]]</paper-button>
        </div>
      </paper-dialog>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'confirm-dialog',
      properties: {
        msgHeader: String,
        msgDismiss: String,
        msgConfirm: String
      },
      show: function() {
        this.$$("paper-dialog").open();
      }
    });
  </script>

  <dom-module id="dialog-in-dialog">
    <template>
      <button on-tap="Button1Clicked">Open Base Dialog</button>
      <paper-dialog id="base">
        <h2>Base Dialog</h2>
        <p>This is base dialog.</p>

        <div class="buttons">
          <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
          <paper-button dialog-confirm on-tap="OpenDialog2">Break the window</paper-button>
        </div>
      </paper-dialog>
      <confirm-dialog msg-header="Confirm Dialog" msg-dismiss="Cancel" msg-confirm="Do it">Sure want to break the window?</confirm-dialog>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <script>
    var init = function() {
      Polymer({
        is: "dialog-in-dialog",
        Button1Clicked: function() {
          this.$.base.open();
        },
        OpenDialog2: function() {
          this.$$("confirm-dialog").show();
        }
      });
    };
    if (HTMLImports.ready)
      init();
    else
      HTMLImports.whenReady(init);
  </script>
  <dialog-in-dialog></dialog-in-dialog>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer in so detailed! I have learned the followings from your answer: 1) How to merge multiple files into one, 2) If I understand correctly, paper-dialog always closes itself regardless of which dialog-dismiss or dialog-confirm within itself gets clicked.